# how to scale an object with animation nodes and bevel?

Tags: animation-nodes

How can i scale an object with bevel modifier in animation nodes, so that it still looks good?

mine looks like this:

[image]

Original cube (instance object) looks like this:

[image]

or can i change the length in another way than scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify the mesh directly. Of course you want to check "Deep Copy" on the [Object Instancer node](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/object/object_instancer/) otherwise you'll modify the base mesh too.

[image]

Using a [Compose Matrix node](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/matrix/compose_matrix/) you can fine tune the desired scale with the [Transform Mesh node](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/mesh/transform_mesh/) set to Matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just looked at this question and Although I've never used them before, I had a go with shape keys. I dont know if this is what you want or not.

Starting with the default cube and a bevel modifier( I set a 1 segment bevel so the movement and scale of the bevel are easier to see)

Click on the object properties tab down on the right and then add a couple of shape keys by clicking the plus button on the right of the shapekeys section twice and then select key1.

[image]

Go into edit mode and select the vertices you want to move, grab them and move them along the axis of your choice to the maximum distance you want the bar to move by.

Tab back to object mode (your object will return to the original shape, but dont worry), click on the animation tab at the top of the screen and click on the dropdown near the bottom left that usually says "Dope Sheet" to start with and choose "Shapekey Editor"

[image]

Just below this is a parameter that you can scale from 0 to 1 which you can keyframe according to the length you require. Dont forget to add a keyframe with the initial length at frame 1 ;-)

[image]

Because the vertices are being moved in edit mode and not scaled in the shapekey, the bevel doesn't change shape.